# On Alphas, does Gary process audio transmissions?

Tags: alphas

I'm rewatching the series, and have been trying to figure out how Gary processes audio signals, such as cell phone calls and the sound accompanying videos he finds on the net. For example, in "Bill and Gary's Excellent Adventure" it sometimes seemed as if Gary was hearing phone calls, but in general he seems to parse electromagnetic data optically. Setting aside the possibility of sloppy writing, is there any science that could reconcile this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to optically process analog udio signals, you could just view the waveforms.  For digital audio, you could just view it directly.

Comment: As someone who worked with computer speech researchers in the past, I can vouch that someone with experience can look at the waveforms and sound out what's being said.